# How to backup contacts from Sony Ericsson WT13i

Tags: data-recovery, mobile-phone

I am using a Sony Ericsson WT13i. Some days ago it fell from my hand and the display is cracked and nothing is displaying. My contacts were saved on the phone memory. Now I want all the contacts. But the problem is that I can't see anything and so I can't do anything. I tried to backup the contacts using Sony Ericsson PC  Suite. But it is not recognizing my phone. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: If you had an unlock code set, it's fairly normal for the phone to not allow a USB connection without unlocking (to make data theft harder). Additionally, the phone might be popping up a menu asking what connection mode you want (mass storage, PC Suite, etc.) - I know Nokia feature phones (non-smartphones) used to. See if you can get in contact with the manufacturer's support - they might be able to walk you through any button presses since you're effectively trying to do this blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an old cell phone. So backing up of contacts is nearly impossible.